# how to convert sql to json in php?

Tags: php, sql, json

With the first for loop I iterate the first array and with the second for loop the second array. If there is a match i incremennt cnt.

```
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlquery)) {
  $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo count($emparray);
echo json_encode($emparray);

return json_encode($emparray);
```

Comment: Your question title and question contents are not match to each other.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you want is to collect in an array the information that the SQL query returns. In that way, use this code:

```
$emparray = array();
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlquery)) {
  $emparray[$i] = $row["name_colum"];
  $i++;
}

echo json_encode($emparray);
// or
return json_encode($emparray);
```

Note that "name_column" is the name of the column that the SQL query returns. If you have more than one column, you will have to specify which column do you want to retrieve.